# How to add one month to a date and get the same day

Tags: java

I try to add one month to a date depending on weekdays. Fore example the date is the 3. Monday of September. After adding I want have the 3. Monday of October.
I tried to add one month to following date

```
Mon Sep 17 17:30:00 MESZ 2012
```

with this code:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.setTimeInMillis(date_in_mil);
date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 3);
```

But I got

```
Mon Oct 08 17:30:00 MESZ 2012
```

which is the second Monday of Oct and not the third. Has anybody an idea how this workes?

**EDIT**
This is the solution I used like in the answer below:

```
int prevDayOfWeek = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
date.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, prevDayOfWeek);
date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, week);
```

wereby week is the number of the week in a month. Fore example 1 means the first, 2 the second, and so on. But week can also count backwards, fore example -1 means the last week of month.

Comment: If you add 3 weeks to `Mon Sep 17 17:30:00 MESZ 2012`, you will get `Mon Oct 08 17:30:00 MESZ 2012`. What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: You'd have better luck using JODA Time instead of the crappy built-in libraries.

Comment: I expected to get the 3. Monday of the Month but I was wrong... How can I add a Month to get always the 3. Monday?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want get 3rd monday of month, then use
`set` instead of `add`
`date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 3);`

if you want add one month to current date, use
`date.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);`

**EDIT**

```
final Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(2012, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 17);

int prevDayOfWeekInMonth = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
int prevDayOfWeek = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

date.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, prevDayOfWeek);
date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, prevDayOfWeekInMonth);
```

Comment: I want to add one month depending on the 1., 2., 3., ... weekday therefore I tried following `date.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);` and after that `date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 3);` but I got Oct. 17. and not Oct. 15.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a month, do the below:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.setTimeInMillis(date_in_mil);
date.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

if you want to add 4 weeks,

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.setTimeInMillis(date_in_mil);
date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 4);
```

To keep the week always as third week:

```
if(date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)<3){
   date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1);
 }
```

or better do like

```
date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 3-date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: I want to have all the time the third Monday of a Month, started from January til December. If I add always 4 weeks, I think it is not every time the third Monday of the month.

Comment: I will add one `if` section to take care that. Updated the answer.

Comment: I added one better option in the end. Please check. Also if this was helpful, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Calendar` class's `roll()` method, **unlike** `add()` method of the Calendar class it will **only modify the part of the date which is mentioned.**

**Eg:**

```
public class Cal {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        c.roll(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

        System.out.println(c.getTime());
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not working, it gives me Oct. 17. on the example above, but I need Oct. 15. which is the third Monday of the Month

Comment: @user1390816 The above code is just the example `to show how it works`.... the example i showed u is to increment the month by 1

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DATE));//if this is 2nd monday of September
System.out.println(c.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
c.add(c.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 4);
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DATE));//prints the 2 monday of october
```

Comment: I know this but I get the Month depending on day, like Sept. 15., abter adding Oct. 15. and so on. I need it depending on first, second, third ... of weekday.

Comment: you want to increment a month on which date?

Comment: Fore example if I have a date which is the third sunday of January I want to have the third Sunday of February after adding one month.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Inconsistent information. If fields conflict, the calendar will give preference to fields set more recently. For example, when determining the day, the calendar will look for one of the following combinations of fields. The most recent combination, as determined by the most recently set single field, will be used.

```
 MONTH + DAY_OF_MONTH
 MONTH + WEEK_OF_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK
 MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK
 DAY_OF_YEAR
 DAY_OF_WEEK + WEEK_OF_YEAR
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution with a String date dd/mm/yyyy:

```
String mes = null;
String yourfecha = null;
if(yourfecha.substring(5,6).equals("/")){
mes = yourfecha.substring(3,5)
}else{
mes = yourfecha.substring(4,6)
}
Integer newmes = Integer.valueOf(mes)+{How many months want to add};
String anyo = yourfecha.substring(6,10);
String newFecha=null;
if(newmes >12){            
newmes=newmes-12;
Integer newanyo=Integer.valueOf(anyo)+1;
newFecha=yourfecha.substring(0,2)+"/0"+newmes + "/"+newanyo;       
}else{
newFecha=yourfecha.substring(0,4)+newmes+"/"+anyo;  
}   
return newFecha;
```

Comment: Your last `else` is without `if`

Comment: Yes, but it is not sufficient as between the last `if` and the last `else` are other commands out of the `if`'s scope.