# Getting wrong date when I add months

Tags: java, jodatime, stubbydb

I am writing my stubs in [StubbyDB](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/StubbyDB). And asserting the data in functional tests. This is something I am doing in my functional tests to calculate date for assertion (using joda datetime library)

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime future = now.plusMonths(6);
```

And this is something I am doing in my stubs;

```
{{TODAY+6m}}
```

But I am getting the difference of few days. Is this the bug or am I doing something wrong?

### Edit

Consider today is "30 Sept 2016", and I add 5 months to it then

```
now.plusMonths(5) => 2017-02-28
{{TODAY+5m}} => 2017-03-02
```

Comment: Can you please describe what is your input, your expected output and your real result? Otherwise your question is not complete.

Comment: As you can see in above code, it is TODAY. Since I run FTs almost everyday, it takes the current date, calculate the future date, and compare.

Comment: @MenoHochschild, I have added an example. I hope it can describe what I actually want to say.

Comment: Well, if you want to adjust the date arithmetic of Joda-Time to the behaviour of stubbydb then no support. Other libs like [Date4J](http://www.date4j.net/javadoc/hirondelle/date4j/DateTime.DayOverflow.html) or my own one ([Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/CalendarUnit.html#withCarryOver--)) have this support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason**

As per [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusMonths(int)) documentation,

> 2007-03-31 plus one month cannot result in 2007-04-31, so the day of
>   month is adjusted to 2007-04-30.

However StubbyDB use javascript based date calculation which adjust date 2007-04-31 to 2007-05-01.

So this is not the bug but this is how these APIs work.

**Solution**

Found in [sample application](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/stubby-db-test/blob/master/stubs/markers.xml)

use {{JODA_TODAY+6m}} instead of {{TODAY+6m}}

Answer (score 1):

if you start with 30/09/2016 and add five months you get 30/02/2017.

But February only has 28 days.

It looks like Jodatime has "rounded down" to give you the maximum valid date for the month (i.e 28th Feb) whereas the other library/code is treating "30th Feb" as 2nd March (since that is technically two days past the 28th, which the 30th would also be).

Both are valid assumptions for handling dates IMHO and are a good lesson in why date handling is hard.  You'll need to be explicit about which convention you want to follow and you may have to code your assertions to follow Jodatime's conventions.

Answer (score 1):

See: [DateTime::plusMonths(int)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusMonths(int))

> Returns a copy of this datetime plus the specified number of months.
>
> The calculation will do its best to only change the month field
>   retaining the same day of month. However, in certain circumstances, it
>   may be necessary to alter smaller fields. For example, 2007-03-31 plus
>   one month cannot result in 2007-04-31, so the day of month is adjusted
>   to 2007-04-30.

So, **30 Sept 2016** + 5 months = **28 Feb 2017** (according to Joda's logic) and it is not a bug

Answer (score -1):

Here is sample code for adding months to given calendar date

```
public class Demo {

 // create a calendar
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()

// print current date
 System.out.println("The current date is : " + cal.getTime());

 // add 1 months from the calendar
 cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

}
```

FYR [How to add one month to a date and get the same day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12899848/4934505)